# Azure Application Gateway - question about override backend path

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I've been working with the Azure Application Gateway for a while and I have some doubts about the Override Backednd Path option. I would appreciate if someone could clarify if my reasoning is correct.

Assumptions:

- listener: mysite.mycompany.com
- backend: myserver1.mycompany.com / myserver2.mycompany.com

HTTP Settings:

- Override backend path: /images
- Override with new hostname: Yes -> Pick hostname from backend target

Based on the settings above, if I send a request to mysite.mycompany.com, how will the App Gw forward it? My assumption would be that it will forward it to either myserver1.mycompany.com/images or myserver2.mycompany.com/images, but that does not seem to work properly.

Regards,
Wojtek

Comment: Hi Wojtek, Did you found any answers to your question?

Answer (score 0):

> I send a request to mysite.mycompany.com, how will the App Gw forward it?
> My assumption would be that it will forward it to either myserver1.mycompany.com/images or myserver2.mycompany.com/images, but that does not seem to work properly.

That's exactly how it works.